# Node js - Hapi JS authentication with Bell

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, hapi.js

I'm new to authentication with `Hapi` and trying to use [this](http://mph-web.de/social-signup-with-twitter-using-hapi-js/) tutorial to connect to Twitter API  as mentioned in the tutorial, to make the code work you have to `copy the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret from your Twitter application and then add them to your version of the code in the twitter auth strategy`.

my server.js looks like this (changed cliend secret and client id to post here) :

```
 'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Boom = require('boom');

// Create a server with a host and port
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
  port: 3000
});



server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('Hello, world!');
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{name}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('Hello, ' + encodeURIComponent(request.params.name) + '!');
    }
});



// Register bell and hapi-auth-cookie with the server
server.register([require('hapi-auth-cookie'), require('bell')], function(err) {

  //Setup the session strategy
  server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
    password: 'secret_cookie_encryption_password', //Use something more secure in production
    redirectTo: '/auth/twitter', //If there is no session, redirect here
    isSecure: false //Should be set to true (which is the default) in production
  });

  //Setup the social Twitter login strategy
  server.auth.strategy('twitter', 'bell', {
    provider: 'twitter',
    password: 'secret_cookie_encryption_password', //Use something more secure in production
    clientId: 'lTIBJtiRT4G32wwMUYbU4yCRw',
    clientSecret: '6TBrWfoP4QEIB6lrApIxJun1SfLYb4e2fEs3vtrphFpB2FieGg',
    isSecure: false //Should be set to true (which is the default) in production
  });

  //Setup the routes (this could be done in an own file but for the sake of simplicity isn't)
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/auth/twitter',
    config: {
      auth: 'twitter', //<-- use our twitter strategy and let bell take over
      handler: function(request, reply) {

        if (!request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
          return reply(Boom.unauthorized('Authentication failed: ' + request.auth.error.message));
        }

        //Just store the third party credentials in the session as an example. You could do something
        //more useful here - like loading or setting up an account (social signup).
        request.auth.session.set(request.auth.credentials);

        return reply.redirect('/');
      }
    }
  });



  // Start the server

});





server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

when i try to open this `http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter`

get below error

```
{"statusCode":502,"error":"Bad Gateway","message":"connect ETIMEDOUT 10.10.34.36:443"}
```

Also tried to debug the code with console.log but looks like it doesn't work.what should i do?
Thanks

Comment: Are you able to successfully request other pages from your server? Try removing the auth requirement to verify that your server is working at all.

Comment: Yes i can request other pages.i updated above code to show that.

Answer (score 1):

I first thought you are using newer versions of npm packages (`bell`, `boom`, ...) as listed in my tutorial.

So I tried your code and it worked without any problems - with the newest versions of packages and with the older ones.

I think you might have a network issue like a proxy or so.

Comment: I re-installed your original code and used Hotspot Shield because twitter is blocked from my country to access it.then changed "Consumer Key (API Key)" 
"Consumer Secret (API Secret)" as pointed in the tutorial althought you reffered to them as "clientId"
   " clientSecret" in the code.it's a little bit confusing.but still get the same error as before.

Comment: Seems like your hapi app does not request twitter through your VPN but directly. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Ithink so.It's ok i just wanted to run an example.i will use Google+ instead. if you have example for that,that would be helpful.thanks

Comment: Just look here for an example: https://github.com/hapijs/bell/blob/master/examples/google.js